# Passing arguments into promises. Do I have to break the chain?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise

I am new to nodejs and promises. I have a requirement of passing arguments into a callback function in my promise chain. Looks something like below:

```
var first = function(something) {
/* do something */
return something.toString();
}
var second = function(something, item) {
/* need to work with both the args */
}
```

And my promise chain looks like

```
function(item) {
    /* the contents come from first callback and the item should be passed as an argument to the second callback */
    fs.readFile(somefile).then(first).then(second)
}
```

I should be passing the item as a parameter, can I do this without breaking my chain?

Please correct me if I am completely wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap your `second` function into an anonymous function and pass in the parameter this way:

```
function(item) {
    /* the contents come from first callback and the item should be passed as an argument to the second callback */
    fs.readFile(somefile)
        .then(first)
        .then(firstResult => second(firstResult, item))
}
```

Comment: that's not an option to me. I will have to write test to every line of code.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Function.prototype.bind() to pass item to second function

```
 fs.readFile(somefile).then(first)
.then(second.bind(null, item))
```